# Reverse-engineering an equation of state

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, condensed-matter

Suppose we have a fluid of some kind with a (let's keep it simple) barotropic equation of state: $p = p(\rho)$.

Typically, I see that one starts with a function $p$ and $\textit{then}$ solves the equations of hydrodynamics (or Navier-Stokes). Things such as the Ideal Gas Law uniquely fix an equation of state, but often much less rigorous arguments are made to justify the choice of $p$ (often for simplicity).

Presumably, if I know the entire particle make-up of the fluid there would be a unique equation of state describing the dynamics of that fluid, right? For example, in a classical system, if I said that within a volume $V$ there were $n$ particles of type $X$ at positions $x_{1},\cdots,x_{n}$ and $m$ particles of type $Y$ at positions $y_{1},\cdots,y_{m}$, this should uniquely fix the dynamics and hence the equation of state.

Asking the question in the other direction: Is it possible, given a function $p$ (equation of state), to deduce what particle composition of the fluid permits $p$? Can I make claims such as there must be no more than $10 \%$ of particle type $X$ within $V$ to allow for $p$ of the form $p = p(\rho)$? As a simple example, what about polytropes $p=\rho^{\gamma}$? Does assuming a polytropic EoS mean that the number of protons/neutrons/electrons is bounded by some number $\kappa(\gamma)$?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Well we know that $\rho=\sum_im_in_i$ (with $m_i$ is the mass of element $i$ and $n_i$ the concentration of that element), so I imagine that the concentrations and masses would allow for multiple solutions.